# Js replace link text with @sometext in anchor

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<li class="some-class one-more"><label>twitter:</label>
   <a href="https://twitter.com/sometext?s=09" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">https://twitter.com/sometext?s=09</a>
</li>
```

**For this, output comes like "https://twitter.com/sometext?s=09", but I want an output like @sometext. I am very new to this, please don't mind if I have done any mistake. Thanks in advance.**

Update: These links are all dynamically generated (added by different users), so I can't change the particular text. Ex: For some accounts, the link is this one but, for some other account, link will be different.

Comment: The text between the opening and closing tags can be anything you want to show the user. You can change it to any static value, the anchor will still work because of the `href` attribute. Do you want to change the label dynamically?

Comment: Not label, I want the anchor text output to be like "@sometext". Now the output is: "twittter:https://twitter.com/sometext?s=09". Please help

Answer (score 0):

Just change the text inside the a tag.

```
<li class="some-class one-more"><label>twitter:</label>
   <a href="https://twitter.com/sometext?s=09" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">@sometext</a>
</li>
```

If you want to change the links dynamically, add this script:

```
<script>
  document.querySelector('a[href="https://twitter.com/sometext?s=09"]').innerHTML = '@sometext';
</script>
```

This code assumes that your links are unique, so if two elements have the same href attributes, only the first element will be changed. Use this instead if you aren't sure that the links are unique or use an id.

```
<script>
  document.querySelectorAll('a[href="https://twitter.com/sometext?s=09"]').foreach((item)=>{
      item.innerHTML = '@sometext';
  });
</script>
```

You can put it in a for loop to change the text for more than one link. With an array it should do the trick:

```
<script>
  var links = [
    ['a[href="https://twitter.com/sometext?s=09"]', '@sometext'],
    ['http://yourlink2', 'the text']
  ]

  links.foreach((item)=>{
    document.querySelector('a[href="'+item[0]+'"]').innerHTML = item[1];
  })
</script>
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: These are all dynamically generated, so I can't change the particular text. Ex: For some, the link is this one but for some other account, link is different.

Comment: Just to understand more your question, if you change the particular text dynamically does it solve your question?

Comment: Yes, if I could change the text dynamically for all similar links, it would work.